# SQL Server : how can I optimize this query 100000 queries +

Tags: sql-server, optimization, statistics

I need to do some statistics which shall make a new table with results

I need to check every second over three years if a condition is met and then insert the result.

Can I do this more efficiently with a readymade table with the seconds (unixtimestamp) or with some type of self join?

```
DECLARE @i int = 1356999800

WHILE @i < 1356999900 
BEGIN
    insert into tablexxx (unixtimestamp, unit, activated, datum)
       select 
          @i as unixtimastamp, '243-1080' as unit, 
          count(*) as activated,
          dbo.UNIX_TIMESTAMP_TO_DATETIME(@i) as datum
       from 
          table2 
       where 
          table2.date <= dbo.UNIX_TIMESTAMP_TO_DATETIME(@i) 
          and table2.date2 >= dbo.UNIX_TIMESTAMP_TO_DATETIME(@i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the native datatype on the table is DateTime, I think I would avoid doing the integer conversion on the function in each iteration of the While loop.

Put an Index on the DateTime field and whatever field you need to count.  If you need to use a while loop do it on the indexed field in its native datatype.  Change the variable to a DateTime and do a DATEADD(SECOND, 1, @i)

Calling the function is most likely adding overhead even if its a small function.  Scalar functions aren't known for their optimization.  If you need the Unix TimeStamp, perhaps go the other way and build a function for DateTime to Unix Timestamp.  Or build a map table to do a DateTime and UnixTimeStamp field and Join your Table2 to the map table to get the specific values.

You can probably avoid using a while loop altogether and just pickup the full result set and insert it in batch.